# KeyListener not firing events in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

I have a `JTextfield` with a `Keylistener` attached like this:

```
field.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            log.debug("KEY PRESSED");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            log.debug("KEY TYPED");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            log.debug("KEY RELEASED");
        }
});
```

But when I type some keys I can see that the `keyReleased` is not always firing. I can't type any keys directly afterwards if it doesn't fire, I have to click into the text field again or type another key to get the released event firing (the typed key is not showing in the text field). I'm not doing anything else with Keys, no event gets consumed. It feels like the event does get fired random. Same happens with `KeyListener` instead of `KeyAdapter`:

```
field.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
```

I'm using Linux 64bit, but this also occurs on Win8 and Win10 64bit. Also tried different keyboards and different computers.

How can I get the event firing properly?

Comment: Don't use `KeyListener` with text components, use a `DocumentListener` instead

Comment: Which keys do cause problems? As you registered the `KeyListener` on the text field, the typed key must be in the text field. E.g. `TAB` might change the focus onto the next component.

Comment: @hotzst It happens with any key from a-z including numbers.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The problem is I need the typed key because of special events that have to happen when I press for example the arrow keys. Didn't find any solution for those in the document listener. I tried without the KeyListener and removed it but it doesnt help and the events still do not get fired / characters are not showing... Feels like something is really broken.

Comment: I'd still not use a KeyListener on a text component, there are simply to many things that can wrong with. You might consider using key bindings, but you're running an awful lot of risks with mutation problems with the underlying Document

Comment: Note also that you can get multiple keyPressed events if you hold down a key, without any keyReleased event between them.

Answer (score 0):

> special events that have to happen when I press for example the arrow keys.

Swing components use Key Bindings to associate Actions with KeyStrokes.

A JTextField already has default Actions associated with the "arrow keys". If you want to change this behaviour then you need to create custom Actions for these keys to replace the default Action.

Check out Key Bindings for a list of the default bindings for each Swing component.

You should create your Action by extending `TextAction`

```
static class SelectAll extends TextAction
{
    public SelectAll()
    {
        super("Select All");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTextComponent component = getFocusedComponent();
        component.selectAll();
        component.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
}
```

Then you could bind this to the LEFT arrow key of your text field by using:

```
 Action action = new SelectAll();
 KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT");
 InputMap im = textField.getInputMap();
 textField.getActionMap().put(im.get(keyStroke), action);
```